# How do i use difflib to return a list by searching for an element in the list?

Tags: python, search, matching, difflib

I have a list of lists that looks something like this:

```
list123 = [["Title a1","100 Price","Company xx aa"], ["Title b1","200 Price","Company yy bb"], ["Title c1","300 Price","Company zz cc"]]
```

How do I use `difflab.get_close_matches`(or something else) to return whole inner list by searching for a specific inner-inner element that matches a search param?

How I thought it would work:

```
print(difflib.get_close_matches('Company xx a', list123))
```

expected output / output I'd like:

```
 ["Title a1","100 Price","Company xx aa"]
```

Actual output:

```
 []
```

I'm aware of using something like:

```
for item in list123:
    if "Company xx aa" in item:
        print(item)
```

But I'd like to use the difflib library(or something else) to allow more "human" searches where small spelling mistakes are allowed.

If I misunderstood the purpose of the function, is there another one that can achieve what I'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the second parameter of *get_closest_matches* should be a list of strings, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches):

> possibilities is a list of sequences against which to match word
> (typically a list of strings).

To fix your issue, do the following:

```
import difflib


def key(choices, keyword='Company xx a'):
    matches = difflib.get_close_matches(keyword, choices)
    if matches:
        best_match, *_ = matches
        return difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, keyword, best_match).ratio()
    return 0.0


list123 = [["Title a1", "100 Price", "Company xx aa"],
           ["Title b1", "200 Price", "Company yy bb"],
           ["Title c1", "300 Price", "Company zz cc"]]

res = max(list123, key=key)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['Title a1', '100 Price', 'Company xx aa']
```

The idea is that the key function will return the similarity of the best match of each list, then you can use it in conjunction with [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to find the list with the best match.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and effort, I appreciate it! Unfortunately I'm unable to actually get it to work, it seems regardless of what I use as a keyword it always returns the first row, I'll try to debug more and return back.

Comment: @nordmanden I put the first list in the second position and it still returned it, so if you can bring more details... What did you use as keyword?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
list123 = [["Title a1", "100 Price", "Company xx aa"], ["Title b1",
                                                    "200 Price", "Company yy bb"], ["Title c1", "300 Price", "Cpswdaany zsdwz cawdc"]]
for item in list123:

     print(difflib.get_close_matches("Company xx aa", item))
```

You will have to tweak the function to specify "How human-readable" it should be.
You might also check this out: [Find the closest match between two string variables using difflib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351396/find-the-closest-match-between-two-string-variables-using-difflib)

Comment: Hi man, I appreciate the reply. I've tried it out and it doesn't quite do what I expected, this returns a result for every list in my outer list, even if the result is empty. I'll try to modify it and see if I can get it to work